# Insert into table sum of different columns with same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´ve the following tables

[image]

I want to insert the sum of the columns [01],][02],[03]...etc. Into another table with the same schema, even if in a specific table exist only 1 record.

Comment: So, where is your code and what is the problem? People don't like to chase pictures but prefer code text. It is a simple "insert into targetTable (< fieldList >) select id, sum(...), ... from sourceTable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES AS SELECT * FROM 
   TABLE;
   ALTER TABLE TABLE1 
   ADD COLUMN SUM_VALUES NUMBER(20)
    DEFAULT( SUM(01,02,...N))
```

> Is this what you are looking for or provide extra detail

Comment: Yes, it help me a lot